# Place single image on 4 sheets Libreoffice Writer URGENT

Tags: libreoffice

I have a single image that needs to be enlarged and printed onto 4 8.5 by 11 sheets. How do I change from 1 to 4 sheets in Writer and do this? Don't bother spell checking your answer, I need this very urgently!

Comment: have you tried selecting a page size that is 36 by 44, expanding the image to fill it, then printing? Does that happen to print as four pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think LibreOffice Writer would be the best tool for splitting & playing with an image, why not try Gimp, cut & paste quarters into 4 new images to print?

---

As to how to do that in Gimp, I've never tried it so this is just a guess... but it should tell you how many pixels wide & long the image is, so take those measurements and divide by each "side" of however many pages you'd like to print on, then split the image at about that length to get equal sized chunks. Like 4 pages would have 2 on top & 2 on bottom (2 x 2), so 2 per side, so divide length & width by 2. 9 pages would be 3 x 3, etc...

Maybe an invisible/non-printing layer with the split grid lines would help to copy the right sections? -- Actually GIMP already has similar features built-in, **Guides** and **Grid** (in view menu, settings in image menu), can set spacing and show lines over your image/workspace, not part of the image.

There should be lots of good how-to guides on everything GIMP-related somewhere on the web, try a web search and pick one that you're comfortable with that looks like it does what you want.

Actually, I'm sure there are printing companies with large-format printers that could print on very large sheets of paper (or even posters or plastic/cloth), it would be easier but more expensive to call them and get a big sheet printed there?

Comment: What about into 9?